# Laravel Livewire reloads page and therefore removes certain classes

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

First, let me show you my problem before explaining it.

[image: Livewire problem]

I use wire:model.lazy="date" to define the date, but whenever livewire detects the execute. The page switches back to it's default layout. Which means the d-none class is removed from the class I clicked on. Is their a way to prevent this?

Comment: Maybe [`defer`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#deferred-updating) is what you're looking for rather than [`lazy`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#lazy-updating)?

Comment: I tried but no difference

Comment: try this to rim dev tag  wire:ignore.self

Comment: You're right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div wire:ignore>
    YOUR CODE
</div>
```

Did the trick